# Why is variable-length array working in this C code?

Tags: c, arrays

```
#include "stdio.h"

int main()
    {
        int n;
        printf("Enter n:\n");
        scanf("%d",&n);

        int arr[n][n];
        arr[3][3] = 4;
        printf("%d",arr[3][3]);
        getchar();
        return 0;
    }
```

Wasn't using `int arr[n]`, where n is a variable, illegal in C? I am trying to understand what's happening here. Apparently the code works on my `clang LLVM compiler` and on [IDEOne](http://ideone.com/QLnqqO) and on Codeblocks. I guess the compiler is just making things easy for me, by doing automatic memory allocation. But another astounding fact is that when I try to set `n` to 1, 2  or 3 it still works.

Comment: They're illegal in ANSI C. They were added to the standard in C99.

Answer (score 6):

Variable length arrays are allowed by C standard since C99. Note that they are still not allowed by C++
standard.
Also important point to note is for versions before c99 and for most C++ compilers variable length arrays are supported by implementations in the form of extensions.

Comment: @AneeshDogra Because you're invoking [undefined behavior](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15646973/how-dangerous-is-it-to-access-an-array-out-of-bounds) and got lucky (or unlucky depending on how you look at it).

Comment: In fact, 3 is the same case. Your example is legal with `n >= 4`.