# pointing to a memory address outside an array boundary

Tags: c++, c

I was wondering if accessing an array outside its boundary(line 2 in the following code sample) would ever produce an error?

```
int a[20];
int* ptr = &a[20]; // line 2
int count=20;
do
{
  ptr--;
  printf("%d",*ptr);
}while(--count!=0);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15646973/how-dangerous-is-it-to-access-an-array-out-of-bounds

Comment: Is this C or C++? One makes `&a[20]` well-defined and the other has hot debate.

Comment: the frist doesnt even talk about any error that might creep in if the above syntax is used

Answer (score 5):

According to [C Traps and Pitfalls](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201179288):

> But how can it make sense to refer to an element that doesn't exist?
>   Fortunately we do not have to refer to this element, merely to its 
>   address, and that address does exist in every C implementation we have
>   encountered. Moreover, ANSI C explicitly permits this usage: the address
>   of the nonexistent element just past the end of an array may be taken and
>   used for assignment and comparison purposes. Of course it is illegal
>   actually to *refer* to that element!

Answer (score 2):

Trying to access memory beyond the end of the array is `undefined behavior`. However, It is perfectly legal to have a pointer to point at one element beyond the end of the array. 
The distinction between pointing to a certain address and accessing it is important.

For example, you can use the following to find the size of an array `arr`

```
int size = (&arr)[1] - arr;
```

Answer (score 1):

Accessing memory address outside an array boundary may not crash the the process always. But certainly it will corrupt the address space if you modify the data. Also, sometime memory address outside an array boundary will really lie outside the process address space, that will result in seg-fault.
Anyway, this is a dangerous. It will introduce hard to narrow-down error. The memory corruption, or weird behavior of the program will manifest at some other place, and we will spend hours and hours finding the needle in the haystack.

Answer (score 1):

Modifying the address past array boundary will never produce a compiler error, since C compiler doesn't treat it as error.
However on some machines if this address is not allowed to be accessed, you may get a Runtime Error (Seg Fault).

This is similar to writing to address `0 (NULL)`.

On a microprocessor/microcntroller/embedded devices on some architectures, you may be allowed to write at address `0`, it is perfectly valid but on some other machines you may get `SEGFAULT`.

That is why this is also termed as `undefined behavior`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not access memory beyond the end of the array.
so changes your code little. **Count changed to 100 from 20**

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
int a[20];
int* ptr = &a[20]; // line 2
int count=100;
do
{
  ptr--;
  printf("%d",*ptr);
}while(--count!=0);
return 0;
}
```

see http://codepad.org/X8yqrnDC

**NO at compilation it will not give any error.**

**But at run time it might get segmentation fault.**

as per standard its **undefined behavior**

Comment: No. The code does not *access* memory beyond the end of the array.

Comment: actually i only want to point to a memory beyond the array, not access it...i will update my question .

Comment: @thunderbird if you are not going to access it then why you need to point beyond the array.?

Comment: @Mr.32 using a similar construct in an embedded project i am working on  and was just wondering if it was legal to do that.

Comment: In what scenario will it cause a segmentation fault?