# printf unexplained behavior

Tags: c

Recently I started learning **C** by myself, so might be a bit newbie question.
I have compiled the following commands:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int arr[5]={0};
  int arr2[5]={0};
  printf("%d\n",arr[5]); //here output: 2130567168
  printf("%d\n",arr2[5]); //here output: 0
  return 0;
}
```

can anybody explain the reason for the different outputs?

Comment: you do realise that you are accessing your arrays out of bounds? you only allocated space for 5 ints for both yet you are trying to access a sixth one

Comment: possible duplicate of [How dangerous is it to access an array out of bounds?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15646973/how-dangerous-is-it-to-access-an-array-out-of-bounds)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are acessing data which is outside of the declared range. The index range of your array which has been declared as `arr[5]`, goes from 0...4, but you want to access arr[5], which is neither defined nor allocated. Thus you get random answers depending on the value of the memory "cell" you want to access, in this case 0 and the other number.

Comment: thanx, worked with fortran90 still not used to the syntax. why the second one returned 0 though?

Comment: Because you are lucky? Run the program some times, and look at the output.

Comment: i did and it is still the same... this is what confused me

Comment: Nothing prohibits UB being deterministic.

Answer (score 3):

Both `printf`s produce undefined behavior, because they are accessing elements past the end of their corresponding arrays. The valid range for indexes of C arrays is zero through `length-1`, so for both arrays in your program that would be 0..4, inclusive.

Accessing element at index 5 is past the end of the array, so different compilers can produce different behavior, ranging from printing garbage to crashing.

Comment: nasal demons are more entertaining, and they are not strictly somewhere between garbage output and crash.

Answer (score 2):

This is **undefined behavior**. C does not perform [bound checking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounds_checking) on array.

Answer (score 2):

In the future, please enable warnings on your compiler. For example for GCC, this would be `-Wall`.

```
main.cpp:7:29: warning: array subscript is above array bounds [-Warray-bounds]
         printf("%d\n",arr[5]); //here output: 2130567168
                             ^
main.cpp:8:30: warning: array subscript is above array bounds [-Warray-bounds]
         printf("%d\n",arr2[5]); //here output: 0
```

Note that the C standard says this is undefined behavior:

§J.2

> 1 The behavior is undefined in the following circumstances:
>
> — An array subscript is out of range, even if an object is apparently
>   accessible with the given subscript (as in the lvalue expression
>   a[1][7] given the declaration int a[4][5]) (6.5.6).

Receive your usual lecture about [undefined behavior](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?UndefinedBehavior).

Comment: Why is someone compiling without -Wall?

Answer (score 0):

The behavior of this code in C is described in section 6.7.8.21 of the C specification ([Online draft for c specs](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf)): for the elements that don't have a specified value, the compiler initializes pointers to NULL and arithmetic types to zero (and recursively applies this to aggregates).

Please refer the above document to know . also i am not posting answer directly here as You are newbie as i don't wanna spoon -feed you. Happy Learning. .