# Scanning the Array of pointers issue

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, malloc

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define SIZE 3
int main() 
{
char *arr[5];
for(i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
arr[i] = (char *)malloc(SIZE * sizeof(char));
scanf("%s",arr[i]);
}
for(i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
printf("%s",arr[i]);
}
return 0;
}
```

In the above code i am scanning more than 3(SIZE) characters but it is working fine.what is the issue?

Comment: You are using linux?

Comment: Undefined behavior. It includes seemingly sensible behavior.

Comment: @Karthikeyan.R.S yes i am using linux

Comment: @RSahu could you please explain little brief

Comment: When you call `malloc(3)`, it is possible that you get the equivalent of `malloc(16)` because the standard library implementation doesn't want to divide memory into such small chunks. But another implementation might give you just `3` bytes. In the first case, you will get away with reading upto 15 characters while in the second case, you won't.

Answer (score 0):

It is undefined behavior. In linux, doesn't strictly follows the array out of bounds. If there is a free memory it will allow you to access that memory. Refer this [link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15646973/how-dangerous-is-it-to-access-an-array-out-of-bounds)

In windows, it will strictly follow the array out of bounds. In linux, we have make sure that we are not accessing the out of memory.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it works but it is not safe. arr[i] is just an address in RAM when you do `scanf("%s",arr[i]);` The characters read will be stored sequentially into the adress starting from pointed out by arr[i].

Lets say you had a memory of 100 chars when you did malloc you may get addresses 10, 20, 30, 40 and 50. Even when you read 5 characters into each of these starting addresses it works. But in case if malloac returns address pointers to 10, 13, 16, 19 and 22. When you do `scanf("%s",arr[0]);` with 5 chars say 'abcde' the string will be stored in locations from 10 to 15 (one for \0). When you do `scanf("%s",arr[1]);` with input 'fghij' it will start writing from location 13. Now if you do printf on arr[0] you will get abcfghij.

This behavior depends on the compiler.