# Is this End of Transmission character or something else?

Tags: c, arrays, ascii

So I'm doing a string basics tutorial in standard C.

I have:

```
char mystring[] = "HAL";
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) 
    mystring[i] += 1;
for (int k = 0; k < 10; k++)
    printf("\n %d", mystring[k]);
```

which outputs:

```
73
66
77
0
4
0
0
0
0
0
```

Now mystring[3] = 0 makes sense to me because I read that string literals terminate in a null character so the number of bytes is n+1 chars. I have no idea why mystring[4] = 4 though. I looked 4 up in an ascii table and it says it's "end of transmission". I did a few quick google searches on end of transmission character for C strings and didn't find anything. So would somebody tell me what's going on here please? Is this a standard thing? When exactly can I expect it to happen?

Answer (score 5):

You're accessing **out of bounds memory**. You *can't really know* what's in it. There may be anything from the `4` you found, to just a `0`, a *Thunder Cat* or [a demon may come out of your nose](http://catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html).

By the [C Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/) definition, accessing out of bounds memory is [Undefined Behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

---

### Might Interest you

- [How dangerous is it to access an array out of bounds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15646973/how-dangerous-is-it-to-access-an-array-out-of-bounds)
- [Undefined, unspecified and implementation-defined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior?rq=1)
- [What happens to a declared, uninitialized variable in C? Does it have a value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597405/what-happens-to-a-declared-uninitialized-variable-in-c-does-it-have-a-value/1597426#1597426)

Answer (score 3):

Accessing beyond array boundary is *undefined behaviour*.

Comment: Ah crap I keep forgetting this, thank you. I'll give you the points when it lets me because you were first. Thanks to the other answerers too I appreciate your input.

Answer (score 2):

Once you get past the first \0, C does not define the contents of the buffer.  Basically, you got whatever was left in memory from last time that area of memory was used, and it has no meaning within your context.

Answer (score 0):

This line allocates 4 bytes of memory. The 3 that are in the array below plus the unseen string terminator `'\0'`

```
char mystring[] = "HAL";
```

Array indexing is from `0`, so `mystring[2]` is `'L'` and `mystring[3]` is `'\0'`.

Indexing any further is undefined behaviour, so no-one can explain the value `4` which you are getting.

Comment: The `'\0'` is in the array as well.

Comment: @zenith thank you I thought I had already made that clear, but I have added one word.