# C program that returns the initials of a name (CS50)

Tags: c, string, memory, char, cs50

Here's my `main`

```
char* name = GetString();
if(name != NULL)
{
    for(int i = 0, j = strlen(name); i < j; i++)
    {
        if(!isalpha(name[i-1]) && isalpha(name[i]))
            printf("%c", toupper(name[i]));
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

The program works pretty good; it passed all the (check50) tests.

But I'm worried about a possible bug and that is when `i = 0`, could the value stored in `name[-1]` be an alpha character?

Note: the `GetString()` function returns a string entered by the user.

Comment: `name[i-1]` - this is suspect when i is zero

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15646973/how-dangerous-is-it-to-access-an-array-out-of-bounds for detailed explanations on why it is wrong to access memory that is not yours.

Comment: Does the `GetString` function guarantee that the character prior to the first is accessible and not alphanumeric? If so, this code is fine. If not, this code is broken.

Comment: @David Schwartz Nop, it does not.

Comment: You could use `if ((i == 0 || !isalpha(name[i-1])) && isalpha(name[i]))` as the condition in the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually in C, the `[]` operator can be replaced with `*()`.

- `a[n]` is equal to `*(a+n)`;

So, in your case, when `i = 0`, you're accessing `*(a - 1)` location while your string begins from `a` to `a + length`. So, this would result in unknown behavior.

```
+----+----+----+----+
| f  |  o | o  | \0 |
+----+----+----+----+
  ^              ^
  |              |
  a            a + 3
```

Answer (score 5):

For `i = 0`, `name[i-1]` is accessing unallocated memory and it will lead to undefined behavior. Change loop counter to `i = 1` instead of `i = 0`.

As mentioned in comments you need to check the condition for `i =0` outside the loop.

Comment: and check condition for `i = 0` separately before the loop.

Comment: If he wants to check whether `name[0]` is alpha or not. Changing what you have advised will skip that check

Comment: @haccks what Haris said is right. you're skipping name[0]

Comment: @Haris - Haccks has it right.  For `i == 0`, `name[i-1]` ( `name[0-1]` ) yields a negative array index.

Comment: @ryyker, OP's algorithm is such for normal `i` he wants to check both and `i` and `i-1`, but think what he would want to do when `i-1` doesn't exist, like when `i=0`.

Comment: @Haris -  If that is what he wants to do, then he must initialize the first ***i*** in the for loop to 1, not zero, to prevent a negative array index.  That is exactly what Haccks is saying.  He must also set the exit condition in for loop to leave at a value 1 less than the length of the array to prevent accessing un-owned memory at the other end.

Answer (score 3):

Supposing the memory allocated for the string and pointed by `name` starts at `name[0]`, then `name[i-1]` will cause an out-of-bound array access when `i=0`, which is undefined behaviour in C, and may cause all kinds of weird symptoms in your program (including it working properly :-). It's an unfortunate case that is passes all the tests, because it's misleading you.