# Robot coin collection - Dynamic Programming

Tags: algorithm, loops, dynamic-programming

*Robot Coin Collecting Problem*

> Several coins are placed in cells of an `n × m` board, no more than
>   one coin per cell. A robot, located in the upper left cell of the
>   board, needs to collect as many of the coins as possible and bring
>   them to the bottom right cell. On each step, the robot can move either
>   one cell to the right or one cell down from its current location. When
>   the robot visits a cell with a coin, it always picks up that coin.
>   Design an algorithm to find the maximum number of coins the robot can
>   collect and a path it needs to follow to do this.
>
> How would you modify the dynamic programming algorithm for the coin-
>   collecting problem if some cells on the board are inaccessible for the
>   robot? Apply your algorithm to the board below, where the inaccessible
>   cells are shown by X’s. How many optimal paths are there for this
>   board?
>
> [image]

I coded for the above image, and it works well as the output shows 4. The inaccessible cell is marked as -1. However, I made `a[0][1]=1` accessible and I got a weird problem which shows `a[1][0]=3` after initialisation and the output is 6 instead of 5. How is the cell `a[1][0]` showing as 3 instead of being 1? Whatever I change at `a[0][1]` is getting affected at `a[1][0]`. How is that? Where am I going wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int max(int a,int b) 
{
    return a>b?a:b;
}

int robot_coin_collect(int m,int n,int a[][n])
{
    int i=1,j=1,k,c[m][n];

    c[0][0]=a[0][0];
    while(a[i][0]!=-1)
    {
        c[i][0]=c[i-1][0]+a[i][0];
        i=i+1;
    }
    for(;i<m;i++)
        c[i][0]=-6;
    while(a[0][j]!=-1)
    {
        c[0][j]=c[0][j-1]+a[0][j];
        j=j+1;
    }
    for(;j<n;j++)
        c[0][j]=-6;

    display(m,n,c);      // after initialising 
    printf("\n\n");

    for(i=1;i<m;i++)
    {
         for(j=1;j<n;j++)
         {
            if(a[i][j]!=-1)
                c[i][j]=max(c[i-1][j],c[i][j-1])+a[i][j];
            else
                c[i][j]=-6;
         }
    } 

    display(m,n,c);      // after the algorithm finishes, result
    return c[m-1][n-1];
}

void display(int m,int n,int c[][n])
{
     int i,j;

     for(i=0;i<m;i++)  
     {   
        for(j=0;j<n;j++)
            printf("%d\t",c[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main(void) 
{
     int a[5][6]={0,1,0,1,0,0,
                 1,0,0,-1,1,0,
                 0,1,0,-1,1,0,
                 0,0,0,1,0,1,
                 -1,-1,-1,0,1,0};

     printf("%d",robot_coin_collect(5,6,a));
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: while(a[0][j]!=-1)
    {
        c[0][j]=c[0][j-1]+a[0][j];
        j=j+1;
    }
a[0][1] is not -1 when you made it accessible,
add limit bound condition

Comment: limit bound condition? like what? I mean why is `a[1][0]` varying, for values that are changed at `a[0][1]`?

Comment: limit bound like:

while(i<m && a[i][0]!=-1) , while(j<n && a[0][j]!=-1)

Comment: limit bound worked. Thanks for the solution. But I don't understand how that really affected the cell `a[1][0]`.

Comment: OK
, I'll post as answer

Comment: okay..that should help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

problem is your code can modify the cell of memory which is out of the array bounds when there isn't any -1 in the first row or first column

this is strange why there is no runtime error, you can see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239938/accessing-an-array-out-of-bounds-gives-no-error-why) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15646973/how-dangerous-is-it-to-access-an-array-out-of-bounds)

add bound limit in while condition:

```
while(i<m && a[i][0]!=-1)
{
    c[i][0]=c[i-1][0]+a[i][0];
    i=i+1;
}
```

and

```
while(j<n && a[0][j]!=-1)
{
    c[0][j]=c[0][j-1]+a[0][j];
    j=j+1;
}
```

Comment: Totally get that. Just because arrays are contiguous memory blocks, after `j` exceeds the array bounds of `a[0][j]`, the array positions at `a[1][j]` got affected until it encountered `a[1][j]!=-1` at position `j=3`. The link helped and  thanks for the detailed solution.

Comment: not always, depends on OS memory management to give which address to the process. I edited answer a bit check it, good luck.

Answer (score 0):

```
int CoinCollecting(int c[][], int M[][],int i,int j){
    int Max(int a,int b) 
    {
        return a>b?a:b;
    }
    if(i==0 || j==0)
    {
        M[i][j]=0;
        return 0;
    }
    if(m[i-1][j]<0)
    {
        M[i-1][j]=CoinCollecting(c[][],M[][],i-1,j);
    }

if(m[i][j-1]<0)
{
    M[i][j-1]=CoinCollecting(c[][],M[][],i,j-1);
}

M[i][j]=Max(M[i-1][j],M[i][j-1]+c[i][j]);
return M[i][j]
}
```