# Creating a million (or more) string array in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, memory

I'm running into a problem creating an array big enough to store words from a large text document (think books).

Usually, I would just do:

```
char wordList[1000000][30];
```

But, as expected the program crashes as soon as it tries to initialize the array.  So, I tried a few different things, such as:

```
char *wordList[30]
int k=0;
while(k<1000000){
   wordList[k]= malloc(sizeof(char)*30);
   k++;
}
```

This, too, didn't work. So I'm wondering if there is an easier way. I know its possible. For the first option, my research as lead my to believe the the variable is initialized on the stack (which has small memory) and segfaults.

I'm not sure why the second one fails. Any suggestions? I've searched everywhere I could to find an answer, but most of the suggestions are in java or c++ where you just call new, or arraylist etc.

Comment: `wordList` is an array of 30 `char*` pointers. You are accessing way beyond the limit of this array.

Comment: The stack size is limited to a few megabytes (1-8 usually, depending on platform).  For such a big array, the whole thing must be allocated (or static duration) memory.  Since many words will be a lot shorter than 29 characters, you're almost certainly wasting quite a lot of space by trying to allocate 30 million bytes.  You could do it all in one allocation if you're careful and use a fixed size array.

Comment: Hint: What is the name of this web site?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`wordList` is an array of 30 `char*` pointers. You are accessing way beyond the limit of this array. Specifically, you are accessing up to million spaces, but the array only has 30 spaces. This will cause [undefined behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15646973/how-dangerous-is-it-to-access-an-array-out-of-bounds).

You need to instead make sure `wordList` has enough space for `1000000` pointers.

This should be instead:

```
char *wordList[1000000];
```

This allows flexibility on the length of the words. The only fixed size here is the array size.

If you use:

```
wordList[k]= malloc(sizeof(char)*30);
```

Moreover, this will run into issues if the words are more than `29` characters, excluding the `\0` character at the end. Although, their are not many words longer than `29` characters. Words as long as:

> *supercalifragilisticexpialidocious*

Are hard to come by.

Furthermore, it depends on how you are reading these words from your text document. If you parse the words, and instead use a temporary buffer to store them, then you can do this:

```
wordList[k]= malloc(strlen(word)+1); /* +1 for null-terminator */
```

Which will allocate memory for any sized word you copy into `wordList[k]`. This will be more efficient for smaller words like `"the"` and `"or"`, instead of allocating `30` spaces for any word.

**Note:** Allocating a million pointers on the heap beforehand is also very wasteful, this process should be done on an *as needed* basis. It might even be better to use `char **wordList`, to allow more flexibility with how many words you allocate.

For example, you could allocate a starting size:

```
size_t start_size = 1000;
char **wordList = malloc(start_size * sizeof(*wordlist));
```

Then if more words are found, you can [`realloc()`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_realloc.htm) more space as needed.

> `realloc()` resizes block of memory it points to, and returns a pointer.

An example would be:

```
if (start_size == word_count) {
    start_size *= 2;
    wordList = realloc(wordList, start_size * sizeof(*wordList));
    if (wordList == NULL) {
        /* handle exit */
```

Which would return a pointer which holds `start_size * 2` spaces.

You should also check the return of `malloc()` and `realloc()`, as they can return `NULL` if unsuccessful.  At the end of your program, you should also [`free()`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_free.htm) the pointers allocated from `malloc()`.

Comment: Thank you, this was the part I was missing. Added the null aspect also.

Comment: @Tanner As I said, it depends on how the OP is reading his document. It would be very wasteful to allocate 1000000 pointers on the heap as the start.

Answer (score 5):

In practice, a good **rule of thumb** when programming in C is that **"big" data should be allocated in *heap memory***.

<sup>(I am guessing that you are coding for an ordinary laptop or desktop machine running some common operating system; I'm actually thinking of a desktop Linux computer, like the machine I am answering here; but you could adapt my answer to a desktop running some Windows, to a tablet running some Android, to an Apple computer running some MacOSX)</sup>

Notice that your current `wordList` is 30 megabytes (that is `sizeof(wordList)==30000000`). That is big! But in some cases not big enough (probably not enough for the whole Saint James bible, and certainly not for the entire laws, decrees, and juridictions of US or of France, or for the archive of a century-old newspaper). You can easily find textual data of more than several dozens of megabytes today, such as all the messages on StackOverflow.

You may need to understand more about current [operating systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system) to understand all of my answer; I recommend reading [*Operating Systems: Three Easy Pieces*](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/) and, if your computer runs Linux and you want to code for Linux, [*Advanced Linux Programming*](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/).

You don't want to allocate a big array (or any kind of big data) as local variables (or with [alloca(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/alloca.3.html) ...) on your [call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack), because the call stack is [limited](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/340961/40065) (typically to one megabyte, or a few of them). On some special computers (think of expensive servers running some specially configured Linux) you could raise that (machine call stack) limit, but perhaps not easily, to several dozens of megabytes. Expecting a gigabyte call stack is not reasonable.

You probably don't want to have huge global or static data (those allocated at *compile time* in your [data segment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_segment)) of fixed size. If you did that, your program might still lack of memory (because you under-estimated that *fixed* size) or could not even start on smaller computers (e.g. if your data segment had 20Gbytes, your executable might start on my desktop with 32Gbytes, but would fail to start -at [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) time- on your laptop with only 16Gbytes).

The remaining option is *usual practice:* **allocate *all* "big" data in [heap memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management#DYNAMIC)** by *indirectly* using primitives growing your [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space). In standard C, you'll extensively use [malloc](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory) and friends (e.g. `calloc`) - with `free` to release memory. FWIW, the underlying primitives (to grow the virtual address space) on Linux include [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) and related [system calls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) (and may be called by the `malloc` implementation on your system). But the standard [C dynamic memory allocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation) techniques (that is `malloc` & `free`) are hiding these gory (implementation specific) details in the [C standard library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library) (so your code using `malloc` & `free` could become [portable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_portability) with efforts from your part).

Read some coding rules, e.g. the GNU ones, related to [memory usage](https://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/html_node/Memory-Usage.html), and [robust programs](https://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/html_node/Semantics.html), notably:

> Avoid arbitrary limits on the length or number of any data structure, including file names, lines, files, and symbols, by **allocating all data structures dynamically**

<sup>(emphasis is mine)</sup>

Practically speaking, your `wordList`  (that is a poor name, it is not a list but a vector or a table) should probably be a dynamically allocated array of pointers to dynamically allocated strings. You could declare it as `char**wordList;` and you want to keep its allocated size and used length (perhaps in two other global variables, `size_t allocatedSize, usedLength;` ...). You might prefer to use a `struct` ending with a [*flexible array member*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member)

Don't forget to check against failure of `malloc`. Perhaps you want to initialize your data with something like:

```
allocatedSize=1000;
usedLength=0;
wordList= calloc(allocatedSize, sizeof(char*));
if (!wordList) { perror("initial calloc wordlist"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
```

Here is a routine to add a *new* word to your `wordList`; that routine does not check if the word is indeed new (maybe you want to use some other [data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure), like some [hash-table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table), or some [self balancing binary search tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-balancing_binary_search_tree)); if you want to keep only unique words, read some [Introduction to Algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Algorithms). Otherwise, you could use:

```
void add_new_word(const char*w) {
   if (usedLength >= allocatedSize) {
     size_t newsize = 4*usedLength/3+10;
```

<sup>(heuristically, we don't want to re-allocate `wordList` too often; hence the "geometrical" growth above)</sup>

```
     char**newlist = calloc(newsize*sizeof(char*));
     if (!newlist) { perror("calloc newlist"); exit(FAILURE); };
     memcpy (newlist, wordList, usedLength*sizeof(char*));
     free (wordList);
     wordList = newlist;
     allocatedSize = newsize;
  };
  // here we are sure that wordList is not full, 
  // so usedLength < allocatedSize
  char *dw = strdup(w);
  if (!dw) { perror("strdup failure"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
```

<sup>we are using the very common [strdup(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strdup.3.html) function to copy some string into a heap allocated one. If your system don't have that, it is really easy to write, using `strlen`, `malloc`, `strcpy`  ...</sup>

```
  wordList[usedLength++] = dw;
} // end of add_new_word
```

After a call to `add_new_word` you know that a new word has been added at index `usedLength-1` of `wordList`.

Notice that my `add_new_word` is checking against failure of `malloc` (including the one called from `strdup`) and satisfy the "robustness" criteria: all data is heap allocated!

BTW, some computers are (IMHO wrongly) enabling [memory overcommitment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_overcommitment). This is a system administration issue. I dislike that feature (because when it is enabled, `malloc` would never fail, but programs would crash badly when memory resources are exhausted).

FWIW, here is the routine to release memory, to be called near end of program (or registered thru [atexit(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/atexit.3.html))

```
void destroy_word_list(void) {
  if (!wordList) return;
  for (size_t ix=0; ix<usedLength; ix++) free(wordList[ix]);
  free (wordList);
  usedLength = 0;
  allocatedSize = 0;
  wordList = NULL;
} // end of destroy_word_list
```

You may want to use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) e.g. to debug [memory leaks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak).

Comment: I like where this answer is going, but I'd rather see an introduction along the lines of "As a rule of thumb, our programs should *use as little working memory as possible*, as this makes them much easier to optimise. However, "big" data should be allocated in heap memory." +1 from me nonetheless.

Comment: @Seb: my focus was not on using as little memory as possible, but rather on being able to use as much memory as is available, when the problem size requires that.