# Why does realloc fails every time?

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic

I have a problem in the code. `malloc` works and in the while-loop, `realloc()` works for the first time and when it is called the second time it always fails.
The code is part of an algorithm to get the prime factors of a number.

```
int main()
{
    int n, in, *ar, len = 0;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    ar = (int *) malloc(1 * sizeof(int));
    while(n % 2 == 0){
        ar[len] = 2;
        len++;
        ar = (int *) realloc(ar, len * sizeof(int));
        if(ar == NULL){
            printf("Error");
            return 1;
        }
        n /= 2;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I tried with `len` initialized to 1 but it still fails. It is strange it does not fail on the first call but it fails on the second call. I have read other similar questions but I am a beginner and I didn`t understand.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Failure to include `<stdlib.h>` and the cast to the result of `realloc` make all the difference.

Comment: @pmg i have included <stdlib.h> and i do not understand what`s wrong with realloc

Comment: Without `<stdlib.h>` included, the compiler assumes `realloc` returns an int then, with the cast, converts that int to a pointer. First: `malloc` returns a pointer and interpreting that pointer as an int may change the value. Second: converting an (invalid) int to a pointer is an invalid conversion; the cast makes the compiler accept it without a warning.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here in your program, **you are accessing an array out of bounds**. which leads to undefined behaviour.

initially, when `len = 0`, in the `while` loop:

```
ar[len] = 2;  //ar[0] = 2;
len++;        //len = 1
ar = (int *) realloc(ar, len * sizeof(int));
//ar is of size 1
```

then in next iteration, when `len = 1`

```
ar[1] = 2; //you cannot access ar[1] as size of `ar` is only 1.
```

this continues with each iteration. To avoid this do:

```
//initialize len to 1
int len = 1;
```

and use `ar[len-1]` instead of `ar[len]` in the `while` loop.

Have a look at this: [**How dangerous is it to access an array out of bounds?**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15646973/5281962)