# Initialized char array with unknown element in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, string, loops, char

Here is my code:

```
const char ca[] = {'h','e','l','l','o'};
const char* cp = ca;
while(*cp){
    std::cout<<*cp<<" ";
    ++cp;
}
```

Output:

```
h e l l o  `
```

Why is there some char value at the end of the array?

Comment: went out of bounds, add a `\0` character at end of array...

Comment: When you write `{'h','e','l','l','o'}` instead of `"hello"`, the compiler doesn't add a "nul terminator" for you.

Comment: To loop over that char array without adding '\0': `for(size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(ca)/sizeof(ca[0]); ++i){ std::cout << ca[i] << ' '; }`

Comment: If you can use C++11 then it will be even simpler: `for(auto c: ca){ std::cout << c << ' '; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are invoking **Undefined Behavior**, since you do:

```
const char ca[] = {'h','e','l','l','o'};
const char* cp = ca;
while(*cp) {
```

without having a *null terminator* appended to your string. As a result you are going out of bounds, meaning that you are accessing memory that does not belong to that array, thus the non-expected character you see.

To add a null terminator, simply do this:

```
const char ca[] = {'h','e','l','l','o', '\0'};
```

---

Good read: [How dangerous is it to access an array out of bounds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15646973/how-dangerous-is-it-to-access-an-array-out-of-bounds)

Comment: that make sense! But then how does the loop terminates?

Comment: @NimitPatel when you go out of bounds, the loop will continue up to a point, where the condition of the while loop gets false. Otherwise it will cause a segmentation fault, most likely! I updated my answer! ;)

Answer (score 0):

You should put `'\0'` as the last element in your array, otherwise `while(*cp)` is always true until null terminator `'\0'` is encountered by coincidence.

try:

```
const char ca[] = {'h','e','l','l','o','\0'};
    const char* cp = ca;
    while(*cp){
        std::cout<<*cp<<" ";
        ++cp;
    }
```