# How to find the average of the two sets of data?

Tags: c, arrays

The average of the first data set should be: (80+70+65+89+90)/5 and the second set (85+80+80+82+87)/5, but for some reason my code is not working.

When I run the code I get 17.0 and 219886384 instead of 78.8 and 82.8.

```
int main(void)
{    
    int grades[2][5] = {{80, 70, 65, 89, 90}, {85, 80, 80, 82, 87}};
    float average;
    int sum;
    int i;
    int j;
    for(i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        sum = 0;
        for(j = 0; j < 5; j++);
        {
            sum += grades[i][j];
        }
        average = sum / 5;
        printf("The average grade for %d is: %f\n", i, average);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please indent the code!

Comment: Just remove the `;` from your `for(j = 0; j < 5; j++);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A ';' means the finish of the for loop
so your code 
'for(j = 0; j < 5; j++);' equals to j=5;

Array Index Out Of Bounds!

Answer (score 2):

The average is computed using integer arithmetics: `sum / 5`.  Either use `sum / 5.0` or define `sum` as a floating point variable.

There is a silly mistake in this `for` statement, the extra semicolon after the for clauses is an empty statement, reducing the `for` to en empty loop followed by a single block, that accesses an entry beyond the end of the array.

```
    for(j = 0; j < 5; j++);  <--- spurious semicolon!
    {
        sum += grades[i][j];
    }
```

If you were to put the opening brace on the same line, a style known as Kernighan and Ritchie, such a mistake would become quite unlikely:

```
    for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        sum += grades[i][j];
    }
```

Similarly, if you define the loop index inside the `for` clause, this mistake becomes a syntax error as the loop index would be out of scope in the block:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {    
    int grades[2][5] = {{80, 70, 65, 89, 90}, {85, 80, 80, 82, 87}};

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        float average, sum = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            sum += grades[i][j];
        }
        average = sum / 5;
        printf("The average grade for %d is: %f\n", i, average);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @woz says, part of your problem is that you never run `sum += grades[i][j];` in a loop from 0 to 4.

Another problem is that `sum` and `5` are of the type `int`, so even after you remove the extra semicolon from the inner loop, you will still have an incorrect output. You should instead do: `average = sum / 5.0f;`

Thus, your code should be:

```
#include "stdio.h"
int main(void)
{    
    int grades[2][5] = {{80, 70, 65, 89, 90}, {85, 80, 80, 82, 87}};
    float average;
    int sum;
    int i;
    int j;
    for(i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        sum = 0;
        for(j = 0; j < 5; j++) // CHANGE 1: remove semicolon
        {
            sum += grades[i][j];
        }
        average = sum / 5.0f; // CHANGE 2: ensure that the result is a floating point number
        printf("The average grade for %d is: %f\n", i, average);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

You can run it [here](https://repl.it/JLAN).

```html
<script src="//repl.it/embed/JLAN/0.js"></script>
```

In the future, when you come across such differences between your expected and actual results, add breakpoints to your code to see *what it is actually doing* before searching for solutions online.

The reason you get the extremely large value is that the integer in memory that immediately follows your array (at the hypothetical `5` position is used to compute the "sum" and "average"). (see [relevant SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15646973/how-dangerous-is-it-to-access-an-array-out-of-bounds/15647634))