# Can't understand the logic on decrease/increace 'for' in C

Tags: c

[image]

I coded this and when I run on win10 (Code Blocks) the numnbers don't get organized by crescent order, but when I run it on my linux (ubuntu 14 - Code Blocks) its organized. Could someone tell me why? (the code is very simple and not much elaborated.

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

  int i=0, j, num[2], aux;

  for (i =0; i<3; i++)
  {
      printf (" Enter a value for num %d ", i+1);
      scanf ("%d", &num[i]);
  }

  for (i =0; i<3; i++)

  {
      for (j=0; j<3; j++){
        if (num[j] > num[j+1])
        {
          aux = num[j];
          num[j] = num[j+1];
          num[j+1] = aux;

        }
      }
  }
  for (i=1; i<4; i++)
 {
      printf("%d", num[i]);
      printf("\n");
  } 


  system("PAUSE");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Num can hold only 2 values, you're accessing it past its end.

Comment: Wich error do you have? can you paste your output?

Comment: `for (i=1; i<4; i++)` should properly be `for (i=0; i<3; i++)`

Comment: The `for` loops access `num[0]`, `num[1]`, `num[2]` and `num[3]`. Of thouse, only `num[0]` and `num[1]` exist; `num[2]` and `num[3]` do not exist, because you have declared `num` as an array of 2 `int` values. Accessing a variable which does not exist is undefined behaviour; in such a situation the computer is allowed to do whatever it wants, including transforming the sun into a supernova and, of course, giving different results on different operating systems. Please do not run programs which exhibit undefined behaviour, because I really do not want the sun to become a supernova.

Comment: @Oscar I put the output, can you see?

Comment: There is no logic because **undefined behavior is undefined**. As soon as `i` is 2 in the first `for` loop the progam goes into undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Bruno Dumbra  What are these magic numbers 2, 3, 4?:)

Comment: @Bruno Dumbra  Just don't run the program on win10. It has numerous bugs.:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, do you mean a sequence? :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25636788/841108 is very relevant

Comment: @BrunoDumbra I mean the numbers hard-coded in the program.

Comment: [How dangerous is it to access an array out of bounds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15646973/how-dangerous-is-it-to-access-an-array-out-of-bounds)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your logic doesn't work, neither in Linux nor in Windows. Getting a correct result is a matter of a pure luck, as you're accessing memory **past the end** of the declared array (the first pair of loops uses index `2` and the last loop iterates up to index `4` while your `int num[2]` array has only two elements, `num[0]` and `num[1]`). This triggers a so called Undefined Behavior, which may result in anything, from returning correct results, through crashing the program, up to destroying it.

**Edit**

To add some insight, consider you local variables: `i`, `j`, `num[]` and `aux`. Such variables are usually located on a *stack*, often in the order of declarations (or exactly reversed). Simple variables, like `i` or `aux` may be allocated in some CPU registers, but that depends on the level of optimizations, made by a compiler.

So the variables' layout may look like this:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------
      |         |         |        |        |         | 
  ... |    i    |    j    | num[0] | num[1] |   aux   |  ...
      |         |         |        |        |         | 
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

That implies, when you reach an item of the `num[]` array with index one past the array's length, you most probably actually access the `aux` variable.

So as soon as you input the third value, you actually store it in `aux`, which will get overwritten immediately after with the first execution of

```
aux = num[j];
```

Yet another error hides between the inner `for` loop and the `if` condition in it. Can you spot it...?

Look:

```
      for (j=0; j<3; j++){
        if (num[j] > num[j+1])
           ....
```

See? *Even if* the `num[]` array was 3 items long, this will run into UB, because at the last iteration you have `j==2` so index `[j+1]` would be out of bounds.

Comment: Thanks to all, I get the idea and will try harder...like a thousand times : )

Comment: @BrunoDumbra Please see expanded answer.

Comment: I understood that my array was short and that the first 'for' was getting the next pointer. And that I needed to decrease my second 'for' (j) in purpose of not comparing with another value that is not from my array and cause a UB. Tks!!