# C segmentation fault using variable to index compared to no fault using number to index array

Tags: c, memory, while-loop, segmentation-fault

Why does the following code not give a segmentation fault

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    int i = 0;
    int x [10];
    while(i < 500){
        x[500] = 3;
        printf("%d", x[500]);
        i++;
    }
}
```

But this code does.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    int i = 0;
    int x [10];
    while(i < 500){
        x[i] = 3;
        printf("%d", x[i]);
        i++;
    }
}
```

I decided to do a little bit of experimentation to see system calls with strace and wanted to see how to OS would handle a segmentation fault. I wrote the first piece of code expecting a segmentation fault but did not get one and was confused since I'm writing to memory not owned by me. So I remember getting faults using a loop and got the second piece of code which gave me a segmentation fault. Now I do not understand why using `i` to index the array compared to using an index out of the arrays bound would change if I get a segmentation fault or not.

Comment: it's undefined behaviour.

Comment: you're destroying the return address for sure in the second example, in the first example you're writing somewhere but it doesn't have any negative effect. Undefined behaviour.

Comment: I have never heard of undefined behavior so I looked it up and read a little bit about it. Correct me if I'm wrong but in the first example the compiler knows what will happen when I  write to 500 so it doesn't through an error. While in the second example the compiler can not know forsure what will happen if I have a variable in a loop accessing memory so it throws an error?

Comment: the compiler has nothing to do with it. In the second example you're violating 1 memory address, in the second example you're violating 490 memory addresses, so 490 times more chances to get a crash

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How dangerous is it to access an array out of bounds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15646973/how-dangerous-is-it-to-access-an-array-out-of-bounds)

Comment: Okay thank you. In such that is why Java is considered a "safe language" since access out memory is not allowed?

Comment: yeah, because there are no pointers, only arrays, so boundary checks.

Answer (score 2):

You're going out-of-bounds in both examples, which is undefined behaviour. Anything can happen now, and there's no guarantee that one instance of UB will do the same thing as another instance.