# Why does the last code returns such result? (in C)

Tags: c

I' studying for my test and I came across with a decent code with weird results. I understand the result of the first two lines in main(), however I don't understand why my computer prints the answer like the picture!!

What is s[%d] doing there???
[image: result of the code]

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printstring(char s[]) {
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        printf(" s[%d]", i);
    printf("\n");

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        printf("%5c", s[i]);
    printf("\n");

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        printf("%5X", s[i]);
    printf("\n");
    printf("\n");
}

main() {
    printstring("I am beautiful");
    printstring("beautiful");
    printstring("");
}
```

Comment: You are invoking *undefined behavior* by accessing past the actual length of the string

Comment: I'm totally new to C so I'm not sure why it's an undefined behavior.

Comment: How many characters is there in `"beautiful"`? How many in `""`? What do you think happens when you go out of bounds of an array (and string literals *are* arrays)?

Comment: Well 9 characters in "beautiful" and none in "". I expected all zeros. So do you mean what I wrote doesn't make sense at all??

Comment: Please don't post images unless necessary. The output is text so you should post it as text.

Comment: [What are all the common undefined behaviours that a C++ programmer should know about?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367633/what-are-all-the-common-undefined-behaviours-that-a-c-programmer-should-know-a) It's C++, but many of them apply to C as well

Comment: Roughly spoken: the values you beyond the bounds of an array are at best undetermined, at worst your program could crash when you try to read/write them

Comment: I'd say it would be *best* if the program just crashed.

Comment: Please see [How dangerous is it to access an array out of bounds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15646973/how-dangerous-is-it-to-access-an-array-out-of-bounds). Strange output is just about the nicest result you can get...

Comment: `""` is an array of one char (`char [1]`), that must not be modified. You're accessing (reading from it) out of bounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because arrays in c/c++ has no explicit boundary，in the third call of printstring, the array `s` is a zero-length char array. when dereference value use subscript 0..10, it refers to a random storage in memory which its value depends on the compiler and the structure of object file it generated. and in your case, the string "s[%d]" are just in the place 3 bytes after `s` refers.