# Why is my function changing the value of an input arguement?

Tags: c, function

Variable length arrays are not allowed. But then, I recently learned that user-defined function manipulates the original array, not its own personal copy. So I thought of creating a function that gets the desired size of the array by the user and therefore modifying the size (I also initialized the array in this function).

```
void fill_array(int array[], int size, int in_val);

void main(){
    int n, value, list[1], ctr;
    clrscr();

    printf("Enter the size of the array: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("Enter the value that you want all of the elements to take initially: ");
    scanf("%d", &value);
    printf("\nAfter scanning value, n = %d\n", n);

    fill_array(list, n, value);

    printf("\nAfter Function fill_array Execution");
    printf("\nThe values of each element of the array is now: %d ", list[0]);
    printf("%d ", list [1]);
    printf("%d ", list [2]);
    printf("\nn = %d\n", n);
    printf("value = %d\n", value);

    getch();
}

void fill_array(int array[], int size, int in_val){
    int ctr;

    for (ctr = 0; ctr < size; ++ctr)
        array[ctr] = in_val;
    printf("\nInside Function");
    printf("\nn = %d\n", size);
    printf("value = %d\n", in_val);
}
```

Here's the console / a sample run:

```
Enter the size of the array: 3

Enter the value that you want all of the elements to take initially: 444

After scanning value, n = 3

Inside Function

n = 3

value = 444
```

After Function `fill_array` Execution

The value of each element of the array is now: 444 444 444

n = 444

value = 444

The function did modify `list`. However, as you can see, it also changed the value of `n`. After every `fill_array` execution, `n` always equals `value`. Will someone please explain to me why the function is changing the value of `n`. I don't want the value of `n` to change.

Comment: You declared `list[1]`. That's an array with size 1. You cannot modify the size. What you have is undefined behavior which should not be described further.

Comment: Yes, DeiDei is right ... declare the array once you know the value of`n` with `int list[n]`.

Comment: @YesThatIsMyName and that would be a VLA which was not allowed.

Comment: **Don't use TurboC++** (or TurboC) since it is an obsolete compiler for an obsolete dialect of C++ (or of C). If you want to learn C++, learn at least C++11 and use a compliant compiler (e.g. [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) or [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/), both being [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software)). If you are learning C, learn at least C99 and preferably C11 (and both GCC and Clang support it)

Comment: @AnttiHaapala True, I wrote that as an answer.

Comment: Your `list` array is large enough to hold one element.  You can't change its size.  The only valid index into the array is `0`.  Anything else will index outside of the array and result in undefined behavior.  It doesn't matter whether the access happens in `main` or in a function that `main` calls (passing `list` as an argument).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How dangerous is it to access an array out of bounds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15646973/how-dangerous-is-it-to-access-an-array-out-of-bounds)

Comment: @TomKarzes This is not a duplicate of his question, but describes only why his output is as it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the requirement is that "Variable lenght arrays are not allowed" the only possible soulution is to allocate an array of "big enough" size.

Then you do not pass as `n` the size of the array, but the number of elements.

So you just loop over the array and stop at lenght `n`. You need to rewrite the function `fill_array` to accomplish this behavior.

Why you get the output you get is because of `undefined behaviour`. See P.W's answer for more info on that.

Answer (score 1):

Within the `fill_array` function you are trying to write into memory that is out of bounds for `list` array.  Doing so will result in undefined behaviour.

From wiki article on [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior):

> The behavior of some programming languages—most famously C and C++—is undefined in some cases. In the standards for these languages the semantics of certain operations is described as undefined. These cases typically represent unambiguous bugs in the code, **for example indexing an array outside of its bounds**.

The C Committee draft (N1570) states this about Undefined Behavior:

> **3.4.3**
>   1 undefined behaviour
>   behavior, upon use of a nonportable or erroneous program construct or of erroneous data,
>   for which this International Standard imposes no requirements
>   2 NOTE **Possible undefined behavior ranges from ignoring the situation completely with unpredictable results**, to behaving during translation or program execution in a documented manner characteristic of the environment (with or without the issuance of a diagnostic message), to terminating a translation or execution (with the issuance of a diagnostic message).

Answer (score 1):

Once an array is defined, there is no way to change its size.

A workaround for this is to use dynamic memory allocation and then use the allocated memory as if it is an array. This could look something like:

```
printf("Enter the size of the array: ");
if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1) exit(1);
printf("Enter the value that you want all of the elements to take initially: ");
if (scanf("%d", &value) != 1) exit(1);

int * list = malloc(n * sizeof *list); // allocate memory

fill_array(list, n, value);

// and just use it as an array
list[1] = list[0] + 42;         // assuming n >= 2
...
...

free(list);
```

If you later on need to resize the array, you can use the function `realloc`