# why gcc printing "Segmentation fault: 11"?

Tags: c, gcc

When I ran below program using gcc compiler, I end up in "Segmentation fault: 11", but when I ran the same at "https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c_compiler", it is executing perfectly fine. I would like to know, why gcc is throwing segmentation fault here?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    typedef int myArray[10];

    myArray x = {2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29};//Equivalant to x[10]
    myArray y[2]; //equivalant to y[10][2]

    int counter = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < 2; j++){
            //printf("%i %i\n", i, j);
            y[i][j] = counter++;
        }
    }

    printf("\n\nElements in array x are\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        printf("x[%i] = %i\n", i, x[i]);
    }

    printf("\n\nElements in array y are\n");

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < 2; j++){
            printf("y[%i][%i] = %i\t", i, j, y[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I am using gcc version 4.2.1. Operating System: MAC

```
$gcc --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 10.0.0 (clang-1000.10.44.4)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin18.2.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

Comment: can you use a debugger to see where it fails. Memory is contiguous so it doesn't matter the order of i and j with those arrays.

Comment: "I am using gcc version 4.2.1" isn't that a prehistoric version? gcc current version is 8.

Comment: You have a misconception about the layout of the `y` array. `myArray y[2];` is equivalent to `y[2][10]`, not what the code comment says.

Comment: yes, but that's not the issue, memory is contiguous on 2D arrays

Comment: @Blastfurnance, thanks for the correction. I would like to know, why the program running perfectly on 'https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c_compiler'. Is it because, gcc is strict in boundary checks?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I know, but I think it's useful to point out that the code comment and the loops show a fundamental misunderstanding.

Comment: have you tried to invert the boundaries on i and j and see if it works for you? out of bounds for an array is undefined behaviour. If the 2D arrays are contiguous it works but it's still not clean

Comment: @HariKrishna there is no boundary check in C. Accessing an array out of bounds results in _undefined behaviour_ (google that). Undefined behaviour includes "apparently working fine".

Comment: @Blastfurnace you're right. I started commenting exactly what you said, but I thought "that's not the issue"

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre : the order of `i` and `j` does matter : `y[9][1]` has an address that is `(10 * 9 + 1) * sizeof(int)` beyond the start of the array, whereas the array only has room for 20 `int`s.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The comment here is wrong :

```
myArray y[2]; //equivalant to y[10][2]
```

`y` is actually defined as :

```
int y[2][10];
```

ie. `y` has 2 rows of 10 `int`'s each.

When you then access `y[i][j]` with row index `i` ranging from `0` to `9` and column index `j` from `0` to `1`, you end up accessing the array out of bounds whenever `i * ROW_SIZE + j` (or `i * 10 + j`) is larger than or equal to `ROW_SIZE * ROW_CNT` (or `10 * 2`).

For example, `y[9][1]` tries to access the 2nd value on the 10th row. But there are only 2 rows in `y`.

[Trying to access an array out of bounds has undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15646973/how-dangerous-is-it-to-access-an-array-out-of-bounds). [Undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior) means anything at all can happen, including appearing to run fine or crashing.

To fix your code, define `y` as follows (so it matches the comment) :

```
int y[10][2];
```