# C program Changing argv programmatically gives heap corruption error after exit of program only in debug mode in Visual Studio. How to resolve?

Tags: c, argv, heap-corruption

I have a large legacy program in which programmatically argv parameter is changed programmatically in program init followed by logic that parses the parameters.

In Release mode the program terminates gracefully.

In Debug mode, the program does all the required computation and gives the correct output. But upon exit gives Heap corruption error:

[image]

Error Message:

> ---
>
> ### Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library
>
> Debug Error!
>
> Program:
>   ...sers\AMD\source\repos\ArgvOverflow\x64\Debug\ArgvOverflow.exe
>
> HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED: after CRT block (#62) at 0x00000259566FDC90.
>   CRT detected that the application wrote to memory after end of heap
>   buffer.
>
> Memory allocated at
>   minkernel\crts\ucrt\src\appcrt\startup\argv_parsing.cpp(285).
>
> (Press Retry to debug the application)
>
> ---
>
> Abort   Retry   Ignore
>
> ---

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
       argc = 12;
       argv[1] = "str1";
       argv[2] = "str2";
       argv[3] = "str3";
       argv[4] = "str4";
       argv[5] = "str5";
       argv[6] = "str6";
       argv[7] = "str7";
       argv[8] = "str8";
       argv[9] = "str9";
       argv[10] = "str10";
       argv[11] = "str11";
       printf("Hello world\n");
       return 0;
}
```

I have read several posts about modifying argv, where they claim that such modifications are legal according to C standards. I also tried the suggestion to have the line

```
argv[argc] = NULL;
```

This is not solving the problem.

Comment: Um... Is the argv array passed to main big enough to hold 12 elements?

Answer (score 2):

It is legal to *modify the characters of the argument strings*. [C11 5.1.2.2.1p2](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.2.2.1p2)

> The parameters `argc` and `argv` and the strings pointed to by the `argv` array shall be modifiable by the program, and retain their last-stored values between program startup and program termination.

It is still not allowed to access the array out of bounds, `argv` will have **only** `argc + 1` elements (with the value of `argc` *as in* the beginning of the main), not as many as you try to stuff in there.

Comment: How about accessing past the length of the character arrays? The standard declares that the strings are modifiable, but would this be guaranteed behavior as well?

Comment: @user8393252 my answer says it is legal to modify the characters of the argument strings. The corollary of that is that it is not stated to be legal that you can change characters that are not part of the strings :P

Answer (score 2):

You are allowed to modify `argc` and `argv`, but that doesn't mean that C suddenly handles (re)allocation of these variables for you. `argv` will be an array of type `char* argv[argc];`. It will contain as many pointers as `argc` says that it contains, no more, no less. Similarly, the length of each string pointed at by  `argv[i]` is as long as what the caller passed.

Example:

```
myprog.exe foo
```

- This means that `argc == 2` and `argv` will have the length 2. This cannot be changed by your program.
- `argv[0]` will point at a modifiable string `"myprog.exe"`, size 10+1 = 11 bytes. You can change the contents but not store anything longer than 11 bytes there.
- `argv[1]` will point at the string `"foo"`, size 3+1 = 4 bytes. You can change the contents but not store anything longer than 4 bytes there.

(Curiosity: it is perfectly fine and arguably the most correct way to define `argv` as a VLA like this:
`int main (int argc, char* argv[argc])`, because `argv` decays into a `char**` anyway.)

---

That all being said, modifying `argc` and `argv`, although allowed by the C standard, is horribly bad practice. Don't do this. Instead you should use a local variable and let it refer to `argv` where needed. Example:

```
int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
  const char* argstr [12] = 
  {
    "str0",
    "str1",
    "str2",
    "str3",
    "str4",
    "str5",
    "str6",
    "str7",
    "str8",
    "str9",
    "str10",
    "str11",
  };

  for(int i=0; i<argc; i++)
  {
    argstr[i] = argv[i];
  }

  /* always use argstr here, never argv */

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot mess around with `argv` like this. `argv` is not your's, it has been allocated and filled during program start according to the command line.

If you invoke your program like this:

```
program a b c
```

then `argc` is 4, `argv[0]` points to `"program"`, `argv[1]` points to `"a"` etc.

`argv[argc]` is `NULL`

But accessing `argv[5]` and beyond is undefined behaviour because you access an array out of bounds.

This SO article may help too:
[How dangerous is it to access an array out of bounds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15646973/how-dangerous-is-it-to-access-an-array-out-of-bounds).

To solve your problem: don't access arrays out of bounds.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala edited, you can remove your comment, thanks

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, I created a separate char** variable, and used that variable in the code to solve the problem.

Here is what the new code looked like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int nargc = 12;
    char **nargv;
    nargv = malloc(sizeof(char*)*nargc);

    nargv[0] = malloc(1 + strlen(argv[0]));
    strcpy(nargv[0], argv[0]);

    nargv[1] = malloc(1 + strlen("srt1"));
    strcpy(nargv[1], "srt1");

    nargv[2] = malloc(1 + strlen("srt2"));
    strcpy(nargv[2], "srt2");

    nargv[3] = malloc(1 + strlen("srt3"));
    strcpy(nargv[3], "srt3");

    nargv[4] = malloc(1 + strlen("srt4"));
    strcpy(nargv[4], "srt4");

    nargv[5] = malloc(1 + strlen("srt5"));
    strcpy(nargv[5], "srt5");

    nargv[6] = malloc(1 + strlen("srt6"));
    strcpy(nargv[6], "srt6");

    nargv[7] = malloc(1 + strlen("srt7"));
    strcpy(nargv[7], "srt7");

    nargv[8] = malloc(1 + strlen("srt8"));
    strcpy(nargv[8], "srt8");

    nargv[9] = malloc(1 + strlen("srt9"));
    strcpy(nargv[9], "srt9");

    nargv[10] = malloc(1 + strlen("srt10"));
    strcpy(nargv[10], "srt10");

    nargv[11] = malloc(1 + strlen("srt11"));
    strcpy(nargv[11], "srt11");

    /* Useful code */

    free(nargv[11]);
    free(nargv[10]);
    free(nargv[9]);
    free(nargv[8]);
    free(nargv[7]);
    free(nargv[6]);
    free(nargv[5]);
    free(nargv[4]);
    free(nargv[3]);
    free(nargv[2]);
    free(nargv[1]);
    free(nargv[0]);


    free(nargv);
    printf("Hello world\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can still do `nargv[1] = "str1";`, you just have to understand that you are assigning the address of the *String Literal* `"str1"` to `nargv[1]` and you cannot modify it.

Comment: There is no reason to use dynamic memory here. Nor is there a reason to call strlen on a string literal, you could have just done `malloc(sizeof("srt"));`.

Answer (score 0):

It is totally plausible to have this kind of setup when doing debug. 
One work around which worked for me was to set up a dummy argument list when calling the program, then repopulate argv with the desired data once you get into main.

```
myprog.exe dummy dummy dummy dummy dummy dummy dummy dummydummy dummydummy dummy
```

and inside your code

```
    int main (int argc , char* argv[]){

       argc = 12;
       argv[1] = "str1";
       argv[2] = "str2";
       argv[3] = "str3";
       argv[4] = "str4";
       argv[5] = "str5";
       argv[6] = "str6";
       argv[7] = "str7";
       argv[8] = "str8";
       argv[9] = "str9";
       argv[10] = "str10";
       argv[11] = "str11";
       printf("Hello world\n");
       return 0;
}
```