# Why this line is getting CL.exe to exit?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am trying to set the value of an unassigned memory location in order to get an exception, so what I have been doing is taking an integer (with a valid memory location) getting its address, adding 4 to it (to go the the next integer hopefully), dereferencing it and assigning it a value (1):

```
int i = 20;
(*((&i) + 4)) = 1;
```

This line is throwing an error saying that

> CL.exe exited with code 2.

Is this a compiler bug?

Note: I am using the Microsoft C++ compiler on VS 2019.

EDIT: here is a screen shot of the dark side of the code (added in order to make it clear that this is the only error that I get):

[image]

**I just wanted to know if this was a compiler bug since it was not showing up an appropriate error message.**

Comment: Could you put entire function for review? It may be caused by somewhere else like a missing return value: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/solutions/579027/view.html

Comment: Could you provide a [mcve], please?

Comment: Very probably you got some more of an error message than that - why don't you post that?

Comment: If `i` is an integer then `((&i) + 4))` is not the next integer but the fourth next integer.  We need a [mcve]  to help you.

Comment: I'm guessing `Undefined Behaviour`.  Can you show the declaration of `i`?  Your code is probably generating a segfault rather than the hoped for exception (in the C++ sense).

Comment: VS2019 has an ugly bug that throws off too many programmers.  Just focus on the *other* error messages it spits out and fix those, then the "exited with code 2" message disappears as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How dangerous is it to access an array out of bounds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15646973/how-dangerous-is-it-to-access-an-array-out-of-bounds)

Comment: I can't repro the issue from the posted screenshot.  This problem is worse than I thought.  Use Help > About, the version I use is 16.0.3 (not updated in a while).  The error I see is "error C4789: buffer 'i' of size 4 bytes will be overrun; 4 bytes will be written starting at offset 16".  Which reminds you that this code stomps all over the stack frame, arbitrarily overwriting variables.  Very naughty.  Use Help > Send Feedback > Report a Problem.

Comment: @HansPassant thank you, I will do so!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently it was indeed a compiler bug. [The fix](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/599958/clexe-exited-with-code-2-2.html) for it was implemented and the release is pending.

Thanks to Hans Passant's comments I have opened a bug and it will be handled in a future update of Visual Studio 2019.