# Accessing variable after an array by trying to access a position greater than its dimension in C

Tags: c, pointers, memory, stack, buffer-overflow

Since in this example I'm able to read value of `integer2` thanks to pointer arithmetic:

```
#include <stdio.h>

    int main() {
      int integer1 = 1;
      int integer2 = 2;
      int *p = &integer1;
      p++;
      printf("%d\n", *p);
    }
```

with output:

```
$ ./test
2
```

I was wondering why in this example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int array[2] = {0, 1};
  int variable = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    printf("%d\n", array[i]);
  }
}
```

then I'm not able to read the value of variable trying to point the next integer but that's what I get:

```
0
1
336859392
```

I tried printing the values of &array[0] &array[1] and &variable and this is what I got:

```
161695488
161695492
161695480
```

Not only the address of variable is less than the one of the first elements of the array, but it's not even the *previous* one.
Why in the first example variables address are contiguous and in the second one not?
There is probably something I don't understand on how variables and buffers are allocated in the stack.

EDIT: 
I know this should not be done, but I'm trying to understand buffer overflows (more realistically the buffer should be of character, given as input by an user), and the goal should be to alter the value of the variable. So what I'm trying to understand is if it's possible to know exactly where the variable actually is in memory.

EDIT2:
Turns out that giving -fno-stack-protector makes it work as expected, so gcc is adding by default some sort of protection in order to avoid buffer overflows

Comment: With `p++` you make the pointer go out of bounds of the memory it's supposed to point to, dereferencing the pointer will lead to *undefined behavior*. Same with going out of bounds of arrays, it leads to UB as well. Just don't do that.

Comment: This is *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: How do you know you are not reading `variable`, as opposed to there not being a 0 in it?  Either way, since this is all *undefined behavior", there is no explanation.

Comment: Refer to eg. [How dangerous is it to access an array out of bounds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15646973/how-dangerous-is-it-to-access-an-array-out-of-bounds).

Comment: one of the most frequent duplicates - answered again

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How dangerous is it to access an array out of bounds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15646973/how-dangerous-is-it-to-access-an-array-out-of-bounds)

Comment: I know it should not be done, but I'm trying to study buffer overflows, more realistically the buffer should be of character, inputed by an user, and the goal should be to alter the value of the variable. So what I'm trying to understand is where the variable actually is in memory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The placement of local variables is a detail of the implementation.   They may be placed in any order it deems appropriate.

Attempting to read past the bounds of an array invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).  The inconsistent results you see are a manifestation of that.

As an example, if I run your first code snippet, I **do not** get 2 as the output.  When printing the addresses of each variable, I get:

```
&integer1=0x7ffcfa6e8c24, &integer2=0x7ffcfa6e8c20
```

So in my case the implementation puts `integer1` *after* `integer2`.