# Memory Allocation in c with string

Tags: c, string, memory, malloc, allocation

```
void Strcat(char str1[], char str2[]){
long len1 = strlen(str1);
long len2 = strlen(str2);

char* str = (char*)malloc(((len1 + len2) + 1)*sizeof(char));
if(str == NULL){
    printf("No memory");
    exit(1);
}
for (int i = 0 ; str1[i] != '\0'; i++) {
    str[i] = str1[i];
}

str[strlen(str1)] = ' ';
for (long i = 0, j = strlen(str1)+1 ; str2[i] !='\0' ; i++, j++) {
    str[j] = str2[i];
    if(str2[i+1] == '\0')
        str[j+1] = '\0';
}

//puts(str);
printf("strlen STR -> %ld\n", strlen(str));
for (int i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++) {
    printf("%c",str[i]);
}

free(str);
```

}

Ok I know the strcat function is a string between two strings.
Suppose I put the input "ttt" into the first string
And the second string the input "yyy".
I am now using dynamic assignment using malloc
Now I know we need to take the length of the first + second + 1 the 1 is for the '\0' character.

So my allocation is size 7.

but I need to make a space between the two strings Do I need my allocation to be 8?
because when I do only sizeLength + 1
the program is still working and it still puts a space between the two strings and I feel like the compiler forgives me.

Comment: Welcome to SO. "Do I need my allocation to be 8?" Of course, who else should take that space into account if it isn't you?

Comment: "and I feel like the compiler forgives me." That is just bad luck. You are causing undefined behaviour and anything can happen. It can evel look to work as expected while desaster is waiting to break free....

Comment: You don't return the new string, so there is no reason to create it. You could just do printf.

Comment: @Gerhardh But can you explain to me why this happens even though I assign a size 7 and I still insert the space character and the \ 0 character

Comment: The C compiler does not ensure that you manage your dynamic memory correctly. That's totally up to you. If you do it incorrectly, your program may or may not result in an error when it runs depending upon what part of memory you erroneously write/access and what that other memory is used for.

Comment: @omerbenyair, because `malloc()` usually gives you **more** memory than you asked for (like rounding up to multiple of 32 bytes). This often hides many errors.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How dangerous is it to access an array out of bounds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15646973/how-dangerous-is-it-to-access-an-array-out-of-bounds)

Comment: Another dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239938/accessing-an-array-out-of-bounds-gives-no-error-why While it is for C++ the message is valid for C as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I know the strcat function is a string between two strings

Umm, no it isn't? I don't know what that's even supposed to mean. `strcat` stands for string concatenation (and not "strangle the cat" as one may assume at a glance :) ). Adding a space between them is not how standard library `strcat` works.

> So my allocation is size 7

Yes, that is correct for implementing `strcat` with input lengths of 3 + 3, with space for the null terminator at the end.

> but I need to make a space between the two strings

Not sure why you'd want to do that, but if you want a space character in between them you need to allocate one extra byte indeed.

> Do I need my allocation to be 8?

Only if you need to make room for the space.

> because when I do only sizeLength + 1 the program is still working

It only works by (bad) luck, this time. [What is undefined behavior and how does it work?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/277486)

> I feel like the compiler forgives me

It's not the programmer's job to keep track of correct amounts of memory allocated. C doesn't have bounds-checking of arrays, nor does it have automatic (re)allocation etc as higher level languages might have.

And as someone said in comments, malloc likely allocates larger chunks of aligned memory. Size 8 bytes seems like a very likely candidate for one such aligned chunk, regardless if you actually just use 7 bytes. But this is by no means guaranteed behavior and not something you can rely on.