# Why does not it overwrite data while inputting data in for Loop (Structure)?

Tags: arrays, c, for-loop, input, structure

I'm a beginner in c I've been working on a program in C where using structure which represents students, and variable of structure contains the student's marks. My goal is to input marks for 2 students for 3 subjects each.

```
#include <stdio.h>

// Defining a structure for student details
struct Student {
    int mark;
};

int main() {
    struct Student st[2];

    // Input details for 2 student marks
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            printf("Marks: ");
            scanf("%f", &st[j].mark);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            printf("Marks: ", st[j].marks);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

But had a confusion while writing it, As we're asking for 3 subjects for 2 students meaning students marks should run for 6 times in total. Won't it overwrite the Data ? Like

`Marks: 5 Marks: 7 Marks: 8`

Here, won't it overwrite the last data to the variable since we've not declared the array to store for 6 subjects,int mark[Num_of_subj]. In this case that should be 8 despite user entering 5 as the 1st Marks ?.

Comment: You can always run it to see if it indeed overwrites the structure member marks

Comment: Maybe what you intend to do is to have a list of grades in student ?

Comment: By the way here, ```st``` is an array of length 2 but you are accessing is with ```st[2]``` at some point, which will cause a buffer overflow. If I understood correctly, the line you want is ```scanf("%f", &st[i].mark[j]);```, and define ```mark``` to be an array

Comment: Please include a copy of your console session when running your code.

Comment: But your code should not compile, as a `Student` struct does not have the `marks` member you are shown accessing in the second set of loops.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How dangerous is it to access an array out of bounds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15646973/how-dangerous-is-it-to-access-an-array-out-of-bounds)

Comment: Okay I just wanted to clear my confusion but I've just runned the code and it does not overwrite the data I can successfully get and print it but as usual beginner Shouldn't it be overwriting since we have not made an array to store for float m[6]; ?.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your primary question, the code you provided will put the first grade entered in the first student mark, the second grade entered in the second student mark and the last grade entered will cause [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior); Thus it *can* overwrite data, but won't necessarily.

To correct this issue, you can make the `Student` struct have a list attribute, and since you are inputing floats, it should be a list of floats. Then, you also need to correct the indices used in the first for loop since, as explained above, they do not perform the intended behavior.

Something like this should work :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define NUM_SUBJECTS 3
// Defining a structure for student details
struct Student {
    float marks[NUM_SUBJECTS];
};

int main() {
    struct Student st[2];

    // Input details for 2 student marks
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < NUM_SUBJECTS; j++) {
            printf("Marks: ");
            scanf("%f", &st[i].marks[j]);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
        printf("Marks for student %d:\n", i + 1);
        for (int j = 0; j < NUM_SUBJECTS; j++) {
            printf("Subject %d: %f\n", j + 1, st[i].marks[j]);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Here the `define` is a [C macro](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Macros.html) which allows you to change the number of subject at only one place.

Comment: Okay I just wanted to clear my confusion but I've just runned the code and it does not overwrite the data I can successfully get and print it but as usual beginner Shouldn't it be overwriting since we have not made an array to store for float m[6]; ?. I pasted this same thing here expecting you'll clear it.

Comment: @AlsiroMira Each student has an array of length 3. you have an array of length 2 of students. So in total you have 6 different memory places to store your marks

Comment: @AlsiroMira In your opinion, what does ```&st[i].marks[j]``` do ?

Comment: provides a like pointer the memory location  for the mark of j-th subject of the i-th student. Still the confusion why it is not over writing ?.

Comment: @AlsiroMira Each student is like a house. Each house have a "floor" for each mark. ```&st[i].marks[j]``` is looking at the floor j of the house i.    
You have 6 different floor addresses : 
house 1 floor 1, house 1 floor 2, house 1 floor 3; house 2 floor 1, house 2 floor 2, house 2 floor 3.

Comment: So there is no overwriting because we provided enough space to hold all of the 6 marks.

Comment: Now you have provided enough space to hold it 
But I am talking about this case where there is no array declared specifically for it, int m; only

Comment: @AlsiroMira I do not understand your question, but I believe it stems from a misunderstanding of the concept of array, pointers, and more generally on how the memory works in C. You can read more about it [here](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/understanding-and-using/9781449344535/ch04.html) and then clear your remaing doubts on a separate question.