Why does not using C's static keyword on integers cause shell to abort when I access an array out of bounds?
I was trying to assign a value to a location outside of an array in a demo program in C. The array was of type int, and I thought it might overflow into the next variable I had declared, b. However, after running the program, my shell returned 1 and aborted. When I added the static keyword to the array and the integer, the program printed the value of the variable, b. However, I'm not sure why. What does the static keyword do in this context, and what difference does it make?
Take this piece of code:
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int a[4];
    int b;

    a[4] = 42;

    printf("%i\n", b);
}

When I run it, the program outputs 1\n zsh:abort    ./memory and exits.
However, when I modify it to be the following:
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    static int a[4];
    static int b;

    a[4] = 42;

    printf("%i\n", b);
}

The program now outputs 42. I have heard that the static keyword can have multiple uses in C, but what is it doing here that changes the program's behavior? I have looked at many definitions and still don't get it :(

and I was expecting it to overflow into the next variable - this is the wrong expectation. How the variables are laid out in the memory is totally up to the compiler. The "next variable" might not even exist in the memory and only be held in registers. Or optimized out completely.

"I was expecting it to overflow into the next variable" : this expectation is wrong. This may or may not happen. The compiler is free to arrange variables in any convenient way. Anyway as soon as you access an array out of bounds, anything can happen; it could do nothing, it could abort your program, it could spill into some other variable (that's what you expect), it could lead to strange elsewhere in your code, etc. Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15646973/how-dangerous-is-it-to-access-an-array-out-of-bounds

Attempting to prove undefined behavior is ... undefined. Good reads on the topic Undefined, unspecified and implementation-defined behavior and What is indeterminate behavior in C++ ? How is it different from undefined behavior? and Undefined behavior

@DavidC.Rankin yeah, that was the objection I raised to this question while it was in Staging Ground, but apparently somebody else approved it anyway.

@JaredSmith that was the right call. Finding a duplicate would also have been the way to handle it -- there are at least a half-dozen. But the problem is actually being able to find a proper duplicate. They are like needles in a haystack when you need one, and the "Related" questions -- never are...

Of course, what you're asking is explaining undefined behavior in C. As it suggests, what happens is up to the compiler that builds your code and the computer you're using.
But most compilers and most computers have it so the stack grow top down, not bottom up. Which means that the local variable b has a memory address lower than the local variable a.
The static keyword makes the variable stored into the global/static storage of the program, where apparently they've been stored with a before b, hence the static variable b has a memory address higher than the static variable a.
Overall, you should not assume anything from undefined behavior. It could do anything, and you're up for surprises.

Generally, stacks do not grow incrementally for each variable declaration, rather the stack grows in "stack frames" containing space for the variables (and any other temporary space required), and it is entirely down to the compiler where it places variables within the stack frame. So a stack growing top down does not imply that b will be at a lower memory address than a.

Re “… stack… grow top down… Which means that the local variable b has a memory address lower than the local variable a”: No, it does not mean that, because the compiler does not necessarily allocate stack space for b after it allocates stack space for a. A compiler might, as it parses the code, toss variable names into a hash structure and later iterate through them in some essentially arbitrary/randomish order, albeit likely grouped by alignment requirement.

I didn't talked of frames... I stand by "most ... have their stack grow top down" be it frames or local variables. Outside of that "most", the frames might not even top down at all. Maybe I shouldn't say "architecture" though, but "compiler and computer" like I said in the first paragraph.

No, the point is that when the stack frame allocated, the SP is indeed going down (for these architectures). But within the frame the compiler might very well follow the same ordering as for globals (or any other arbitrary ordering), which does not depend (mostly) on the underlying architecture.

Yup. But are you really contradicting what I say ? ("Most" computer move the stack pointer to each frame top down + "Most" compiler order local variable of a frame first declared variable top, next variable down) -> ("Most" compilers and most computers have the "stack" "grow" top down.) If you think explaining the details of how the stack really work is important, feel free to add another answer :|
